# HP Storageworks disk not recognised

Tags: hp, storage-area-network, hp-storageworks

I have inherited an out of warranty HP StorageWorks X1600 G2 SAN with non-genuine HDDs (3T Seagate).

A disk is showing as amber and the 'Array Configuration Utility' says the disk is 'bad or missing'.

I have replaced the bad Seagate with another Seagate disk, however, it still says 'bad or missing'.

I'm wondering if there is a prep that is required on disks before connecting them? i.e. firmware upgrades to the disk, etc.  (I can't see any firmware upgrades on seagates site, it current has CC24)

Comment: Even out of the warranty you should always order your disk via HP part surfer or a reseller. Always. HP support product for 10 years for part replacements. This is the HP's force. For your question is the seagate disk the same series/model as the other ?

Comment: *I have replaced the bad Seagate with another Seagate disk, however, it still says 'bad or missing'.*  Do you **know** that the replacement disk is working?

Answer (score 0):

The StorageWorks X1600 G2 is a rebadged ProLiant DL180 G6 with a special ILO option. The RAID controller is a standard Smart Array P410.

You can pretty much use any type of disk, although I can't image why HP drives weren't in use in the first place.

Either way, do the obvious thing:

- Look at the specific model number of the failed drive.
- Buy a replacement of the same specific model. It can be old-stock.

That's it. You have a known-good solution (because the other drives work), so just reproduce it.